# Translation of maintenance banner message

Tags: support, status-deferred, localization, maintenance

Should this banner message be available to translate?

> [image]

This type of message has specific structure, i.e.:

> <maintenance...> <...dates range...> <...readonly>

So the staff can make a template of that and allow this sentance to translate by community members. Only dated range will be changed for future maintenance announcements. I know it can be even used according local (site specific) date/time formats.

When maintenance is in progress one more message is displayed:

> [image: read-only mode]

The message on the yellow background is available to translate and was translated recently, so we will check it on the next maintenance.

Answer (score 5):

At the moment, that banner is being used as a network-wide announcement and while it *can* be overridden on a per-site basis to support translations, it's not something we can do without headaches.

Let's say we set the English global announcement first. We then go in and manually override the translation for Russian SO. If we need to update the English global announcement, it will erase the Russian translation and replace it with the new English announcement. And... we'd have to manually do the override process for Russian SO again.

Also, we'd need to get translations for Japanese, Portuguese, and Spanish as well (which are often provided by awesome community members). Considering the short-notice of this planned maintenance, we wouldn't have time to get the translations ready.

But! It is a good idea to support translations for global announcements and something we will try to look into.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please take a look on updated post.